# Css code why the div class going down?

Tags: html, css

I have posted the question..but nobody answered the question..My code is:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
}

.firstnav {
    margin:auto;
    height: 1500px;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
    flex: 3 1 60%;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}

#third {
    background: #f00;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
    flex: 1 6 20%;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}

#second {
    background: #fff;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 67%;
    height: 1500px;

    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
    flex: 1 6 20%;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}

#registration-form {
    font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

#registration-form .fieldset {
    background-color:#d5d5d5;

    border-radius: 3px;

}

#registration-form legend {
    text-align: center;
    background: #364351;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: white;
    font-size:2em;
}

.fieldset form{
    border:1px solid #2f2f2f;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:30px 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstnav">

<div id="second"><p>second<p></div>
<div id="third">

    <div id="registration-form">
        <div class='fieldset'>
            <legend>Todays news
            </legend>
            <form action="#" method="post" data-validate="parsley">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

here,you can see the second content is going down..why it is happening??I want the two container side by side..I have changed the "#second" code but still it is not coming to the side..

Comment: Could you actually create a JsFiddle with your code to help us helping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one line is missing. The elements are not being floated. Try adding `float: left;` to `#second`.

Play with it on JSFiddle. I've already made the change for you. Is that what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/jr0gpaqg/

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/FnK9D/15/

```
#second {
  background: #fff;
  position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 67%;
  height: 1500px;

   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question...change

```
#third {
  background: #f00;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
       flex: 1 6 20%;
  -webkit-order: 3;
       order: 3;
}
```

to this...

```
#third {
    background: #f00;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
    flex: 1 6 20%;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}
```

your positioning was your problem.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldayne/uegc3667/)